# Are there any D&D publications with settings in Mechanus?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, planes

Is there any official published content centred around the plane Mechanus? I'd really want to know much more about the plane and its inhabitants. I feel inspired by the 5e Monster Manual, DM's Guide and Player's Handbook entries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The supplement you probably want is "[Planes of Law](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17272/Planes-of-Law-2e?term=Planes%20of%20Law&it=1)," which describes the lawfully-aligned planes of the Great Wheel in detail. Mechanus is, naturally, one of the planes it covers. You'll probably not find any treatment of the plane more detailed than this; It was released during the heyday of 2e AD&D's Planescape campaign setting, which expanded the planes from being an interesting place to visit into a full-fledged setting for campaigns.

Also... I'm not sure if I should include this or not, since it's not *directly* about Mechanus, but there is a second edition adventure (or rather, a series of adventures published in a single book) called "[The Great Modron March](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17302/The-Great-Modron-March-2e?it=1)." As the name suggests, it focuses on the Modrons: Those semi-mechanical exemplars of Law that inhabit the plane. It contains a little extra information about Mechanus that you might find useful, including its gate town (Automata), its inhabitants (chiefly the Modrons), its relationship with the rest of the planes (especially those in the Great Wheel), its Great Cycles (The giant clockwork keeps very regular time) and its Powers (assuming Primus the One counts as a power).

Comment: Perfect Answer! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @RaxsSlayer My answer is, indeed, perfect. However, it is considered good practice to hold off on accepting an answer until 24 hours have passed, just in case someone sees that there's an accepted answer and doesn't bother to post an answer of their own that might be better than this one.

Comment: That's a good call. I'm still getting used to the nature of this site. I must admit it's very professional and this certainly helps towards getting prompt, sensible answers. So I will definitely take your word for it. Thanks again.